# Ruby monkey patch AWS::S3::S3Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to monkey patch the AWS S3Object class in the AWS SDK Version 1 1.60 gem just for our development environment. I thought it would be as easy as any other monkey patch simply by redeclaring the class and adding to it or overriding things, but it doesn't seem to work. Any methods I try to add are not added. Something as simple as the following won't work.

```
class S3Object
  def blah
    puts 'foo'
  end
end

connection = AWS::S3::new
connection.buckets['bucketname'].objects['object_name'].blah
```

With this I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `blah' for <AWS::S3::S3Object:amazon.server.com/bucketname>:AWS::S3::S3Object
```

I also tried following the module and class structure of the gem by doing this

```
module AWS
  class S3
    class S3Object
      def blah
        puts '***** blah blah blah *****'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

that didn't work either

From the looks of the source code the objects collection should contain an instance of S3Object. For whatever reason it isn't mixing in my new method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're missing the modules S3 object is inside AWS::S3

Answer (score 1):

```
module AWS
  module S3
   class S3Object
     def blah
       puts 'foo'
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you actually I thought I had tried that but I guess not. it worked.